# SSRS Adding a Table to Header/Footer of Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Relatively basic question that seems to elude me - is it possible to insert a table into the header or footer of an SSRS report?

I am only able to get the options for the following:
Textbox, Line, Rectangle, Image

However in the main body, I get a multitude of controls I can add. Is this a limitation of SSRS? Is there any workarounds, other than 'creating' the tables myself using a combination of textboxes?

Worth mentioning that I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 Report Builder 3.0.

Comment: I've tried the following: adding directly to the header/footer, adding to main body and dragging into header/footer, and cutting and trying to paste into the header/footer. No luck as of yet.

Comment: Can you explain in detail why you need to add a table. Is it just for alignment purpose or something else?

Comment: Yes, it was solely for alignment rather than data access. Rather than adjusting to the last point, it would be much easier to design a more professional looking report rather than spending time making sure fields align perfectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSRS doesn't allow Tablix in header and footer. SSRS only allows static data in header and footer. To access dynamic data we generally use `ReportItems` or `Parameters`. Adding a tablix(table) requires a dataset. Thats why we cannot add tablix in header and footer.

[MSDN Article on Report Headers and footers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220421(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the answer with the MSDN link. I thought as such, however I was holding on to some hope that I could actually insert it somehow.

Comment: That's is the type of data I want in the footer, but I want to use a table as an organizationtal tool to align that data.